# Java methods interacting with each other

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I am currently learning Java and following some online tutorials. One of the assignments is to compute the body age of a person by getting their various scores, getting the average of these scores and then applying a formula to it to get the total. I can do it with one big class, but the assignment then asks to go further and split everything into different classes. My program currently looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fit2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int average, bodyAge;
        average = average2();
        System.out.println(average);
        bodyAge = fitAge();
        System.out.println(bodyAge);
    }
        public static int fs() {
        int fs;
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        fs = bucky.nextInt();
        return fs;
    }

    public static int ss() {
        int ss;
        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        ss = bucky.nextInt();
        return ss;
    }

    public static int average2() {
        int first, second, average;
        first = fs();
        second = ss();
        average = (first + second) / 2;
        return average;
    }

    public static int fitAge() {
        int fitAge, average;
        average = average2();
        fitAge = average * 8 / 5 + 10;
        return fitAge;
    }
}
```

My idea was to have different methods for each part of the program - two methods to get the users scores and then pass these into a averageing method, which would then pass it into a final method which would apply the formula, then passing it back it into the Main class, which would print that age out as well as the Average age.

I read somewhere that you shouldnt get user input in classes but get it in main and pass it into the average class using parameters -- can anyone advise on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly are you trying to do, and what exactly is your problem?

Comment: Please, reformat your code and try to follow code convention for it to be readable http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: You can start with creating class Person which will have all the "various scores", "body", "age" fields and whatever else person characteristics you want to have.

Comment: Something that should be noted, is you aren't "passing" any of these user entered values into any of your methods. If you were passing them, your `fitAge()` and your `average2()` method declarations would have parameters as passed-in values so that you could provide the methods with those values rather than have them have to calculate them. This would line up with what @dddJewelsbbb is suggesting below; capture the user input in `main()` and then pass the `bucky.nextInt()` return values to the methods as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (as suggested by my comment on the question):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fit2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        int fs = bucky.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
        bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        int ss = bucky.nextInt();

        int average = average2(fs, ss);
        int bodyAge = fitAge(average);
        System.out.println(average);
        System.out.println(bodyAge);
    }

    public static int average2(int first, int second) {
        int average;
        average = (first + second) / 2;
        return average;
    }

    public static int fitAge(int average) {
        int fitAge;
        fitAge = average * 8 / 5 + 10;
        return fitAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if you explained what you changed, and more importantly why you changed it.

Comment: Thanks for this - does work now. s there any way to put the user input into a class and then pass that into another class?

Comment: @IanMcLaird good point. I had written a clarifying comment on the actual question itself and then wrote the answer. Those should be associated, as the comment explains the decisions for the answer. I have since referenced it in the answer.

Comment: @YusufBismillah yes -- instead of setting the returned values from `average2(fs, ss)` and `fitAge(average)` into local variables in the `main()`, you could create a new instance of a Person class that you create that takes both average and fitAge as values to a Person constructor (i.e. `public class Person{ public Person(int average, int fitAge){ this.average = average; this.fitAge = fitAge; } }`). That way you'll then have a Person object with its inner members set to the values calculated by the user's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand your question - you are unsure of where to place user input in your program.

In a small program like this, it may be wise to place user input in the `main()` method, solely because you gather user input, delegate input to methods that perform computation on the data that is "under the hood" of the program, and then return the value back to the user.

In your specific instance, this seems like a wise decision, as your program is small and a standard console-based application. This may not always be the case in the future, depending on the program you are writing.

Realistically, it doesn't matter all too much if it runs as intended, but for simplicity sake (remember [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) putting user input in your `main()` method is probably a good idea.

Comment: Yes, have done that now and it does work. Do you know of there is a way to gather the user input in one class, and then pass those values into another class?